# How to draw a horizontal line on a word in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, horizontal, cancel

I want to draw a horizontal line on a word in LaTeX. I've tried \cancel but it draws a diagonal line. I checked the \cancel documentation and couldn't find anything about drawing a horizontal line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\cancel` is used in the maths environment. Do you want a horizontal line in the text mode or maths mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible using the package `soul` with the command `\st`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\st{Today not is a good morning}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Comment: @negarpourmoazemi You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you can compile with lualatex, I suggest to use the `lua-ul` package. It overcomes many of the limitations of similar packages like `ulem` or `soul` (problems with some unicode content etc.).

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}

text \strikeThrough{text} text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Could you maybe add a sentence to two regarding some of the pertinent limitations of the `soul` package?